# Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidAMIID.Malformed: Invalid id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to deploy an ec2 instance on aws.

This is my resource code

```
data "aws_ami_ids" "ubuntu" {
  owners = ["099720109477"] 

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
    
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  
}

output "test" {
  value = data.aws_ami_ids.ubuntu
}

resource "aws_instance" "myec2" {
  ami             = "${data.aws_ami_ids.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type   = var.instancetype
  key_name        = "devops-era"`
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.allow_http_https.name}"]

  tags = {
    Name =  "var.aws_common_tag" 
  }  
}
```

But I keep getting the below error whenever I run terraform apply:

```
Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidAMIID.Malformed: Invalid id: "203304658" (expecting "ami-...")
│   status code: 400, request id: 35b803fd-a6c8-4632-82ee-2936c9cbf062
│ 
│   with aws_instance.myec2,
│   on mini-projet.tf line 28, in resource "aws_instance" "myec2":
│   28: resource "aws_instance" "myec2" {
```

I don't understand why

Any suggestions here will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data source query returns **multiple** AMI ids. You have to choose explicitly which one you want, e.g. to use the first one:

```
ami           = data.aws_ami_ids.ubuntu.ids[0]
```

Comment: and now if i want to use the most recent image how can i do?

Comment: you can use `most_recent = true` on your data source `data "aws_ami_ids" "ubuntu"`  to get the most recent image.